# Google Visualization only showing one graph when looping through array to display several

Tags: javascript, visualization

I've seen a lot of discussion on creating multiple graphs in a single page when you know how many graphs are being created in advance. I'm creating a page where I need to graph several items, and it's unknown in advance how many items there will be. The last graph always shows up, the earlier ones don't. When debugging, I can see that all the graphs get displayed when the draw function is called, but it goes away when the next draw is called. It's probably something stupid, but I've searched for hours and can't figure it out. Changing to the test environment (version 1.1) makes all of them appear, but the hovertext doesn't show up. Any suggestions? The code is part of a whole thing, so I tried to create a condensed version with hardcoded data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Summary</title> 
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(summary_go);

        function summary_go() {

            /* skipping a bunch of code that does some queries and pulls the data into arrays for the graphs */
            var graph_data = new Array(
                {title: "Potassium SerPl-sCnc",
                    head: ["Date","mmol/L"],
                    data: [[new Date("2004", "09", "23"),3.6],
                        [new Date("2005", "08", "31"),3.5],
                        [new Date("2007", "09", "01"),3.4],
                        [new Date("2008", "01", "11"),4.1],
                        [new Date("2009", "09", "30"),3.5]]},

                {title: "Albumin/Creat Ur-mRto",
                    head: ["Date","ug/mg{creat}"],
                    data: [[new Date("2004", "09", "23"),5],
                        [new Date("2009", "09", "30"),8]]});

            var labdiv = document.getElementById("lab-list");
            for (var i = 0; i < graph_data.length; i++) {
                labdiv.innerHTML += "<li>" + graph_data[i]['title'] + "<div id=\"" + graph_data[i]['title'] + "\"></div></li>";

                var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Value');
          dataTable.addRows(graph_data[i]['data']);

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(graph_data[i]['title']));
                var options = {
                    vAxis: {title: graph_data[i]['head'][1]},
               legend: {position: 'none'},
          };

                chart.draw(dataTable, options);
            }
        }
    </script> 

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" id="lab-list">
                <h3>Patient Data</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.fluid-container-->

</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it was something stupid. The div tags probably weren't getting set in time for the draw call, so when I broke it out into separate looks - first setting up the divs, then calling the draw calls, it worked without any problems.